# How to open a new browser window with content, in Dart (html)

Tags: dart-html

I'm unable to find a way to open a browser window like below.

```
final winPrint = window.open("", "");

// no document property  
winPrint.document.write('''...''');
```

Is this possible in dart?

Comment: You should be able to do so, have you tried?

Comment: `winPrint` doesn't have `document` property. `window.open` returns `WindowBase` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the WindowBase doesn't expose the `document` object you can call directly the open function and then call the write function on the JsObject like this:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

  var f = js.context.callMethod('open', ['']);
  (f['document'] as js.JsObject).callMethod('write', ['Hello world']);
```